# Removing manufacturer from product in OpenCart

Tags: opencart

For testing purposes I added a fake manufacturer to a real product, how I can remove it?
If I cancel manufacturer name in product page it will return after saving. Same thing if I place a space or underscore.
If I try to cancel manufacturer I get this message: "Can't remove the manufacturer because there is a product linked with it"

P.S. I can not set another manufacturer to this product or remove and reinsert the product.

Comment: Do you have access to the database? If so just find the apropriate line in product_to_manyfacturer table or sth like that and remove it.

Comment: If I had an access to DB I won't ask this question.

Comment: What rights do you have to the backend? If you do not have admin rights there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple script you can add in `/admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl`

Leave the manufacturer field blank and you are good to go, This will simply remove manufacturer id from product.

```
<script>
  $( "input[name=\'manufacturer\']" ).change(function() {
    var mfg = document.getElementsByName("manufacturer")[0].value;
    if(mfg.length == 0){
      $('input[name=\'manufacturer_id\']').attr('value', '');
    }
});
</script>
```

Good Day